# Unpacking (r,g,b) raw pixel buffer in C

Tags: python, c, arrays, bitmap, ctypes

currently trying to use C for a job previously done in python (pypy). I figured i'd try to write it in C (for optimal speed), and use the ctypes to communicate.

Now what I want to do is to take the pixelbuffer from a Bitmap (bmp-file), send it to a C-function that converts the raw buffer to a flat array of R,G,B-values and return it to python. But I got stuck when trying to convert the "buffer" to R,G,B values.
In python I would simply use the "struct"-module: `B,G,R = struct.unpack('<BBB', buffer[i:i+3])`

How should I do the same in C?

**Python:**

```
from bmplib import Bitmap
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.CDLL('_bitmap.dll') 

bmp = Bitmap()
bmp.open('4x4.bmp')
buf = bmp._rawAsArray() #Returns a array.array() of char (raw pixel-data)

addr, count = buf.buffer_info()
lib.getData.argtypes = []

arr = ctypes.cast(addr, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char))
lib.getData(arr, count) #Does not return anything yet..
```

**Failed C attempt to convert pixels:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void getData(char *, const int);
void getData(char * array, const int length) {
  int i = 0;
  while(i < length) {
    /* ----- Clearly wrong as i got some HUGE number----- */
    printf("%d, ", ((int *) array)[i]   << 8); //B 
    printf("%d, ", ((int *) array)[i+1] << 8); //G
    printf("%d\n", ((int *) array)[i+2] << 8); //R
    i += 3;
  }
  //return total;
}
```

Comment: What do you have in `char * array` ? One sample per byte ?

Comment: Even tho it's sloved: @leonbloy, that is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing `array[i] << 8` which is the same as shifting `array[i]` 8 bits to the left, or multiplying `array[i]` by 256.  That is why you get the huge number.  Get rid of `<< 8` and you should be OK.

Also, typecast to `int` after dereferencing the array.  It should read `(int)array[i]`.

Comment: It was just a test to see if the solution was to bitshift. Without bitshifting it's the same problem.. EG the first pixel in my 4x4-bmp (0,0) is `33620225, 50528770, 67372035`, should be `1,1,1`... same probelm concured with bitshifting. But the solution was as you edited: (int)array[i]

Comment: So it seems to be solved, removed the bitshifting, as there was no reason for it, and used `printf("%d, ", (int)array[i]);`
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5):

It's not clear the format you receive the image in the `char * array`. Assumming you have one byte per array element, you don't need to do any shift:

```
 while(i < length) {
    printf("%d, ", (unsigned int)array[i++]); //B 
    printf("%d, ", (unsigned int)array[i++]); //G
    printf("%d\n", (unsigned int)array[i++]); //R
  }
```

Bear in mind, however, that a [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#Pixel_format) image can have some padding for each row, so this will work only if the `array` corresponds to a single row, and `length` does not include the padding.

Comment: Yes i know about the padding, i have removed it before sending the buffer to C. Your post (as well as unxnuts post) is the answer to my problem! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're casting the `char`-pointer to an `int`-pointer, which causes weird numbers. You shouldn't need to cast it, but if you do have to cast the result. Like so:

```
printf("%d, ", (char)(array[i] << 8)); //B
```